# How to click a png and make it auto go up a layer

Tags: javascript, html

i'm making a house designing game of sorts but i can't find anything that would allow the player to click say the "flower pot" png and it automatically moves up above the "Bed" png. When left untouched it was behind the bed png. How can i do this, would i need to use Z index?

https:// jsfiddle.net/okcjt5vf/294/ this is all my code so far.

Comment: Please post all **relevant** code here in a [mcve]

Comment: It's not a problem i'm trying to find a function or line of code that can do the function i desire

Answer (score 3):

you can use the *onmouseup* and the *onmousedown* html property as follow:

```
<img onmouseup="mouseUp(this)" onmousedown="mouseDown(this)" class="draggable" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/spuoop.png">
```

you add it for each element that you need to move up when pressed

and then in js you add the functions to set the z-index of the element needed:

> moving up the element

```
function mouseDown(var x) {
   x.setAttribute("z-index", "20"); 

}
```

> moving down the element

```
function mouseUp(var x) {
    x.setAttribute("z-index", "0"); 
}
```

Comment: let me know if it helped